# Simple graph in Rust

Tags: graph, rust

I have written simple code to construct a graph, but I think there are too many different types for such a simple task.

In this code I need to store `Node` structs in the `Graph` instead of pure values because it encapsulates some logic. The user should not know about `Key`. The user will be working with references to nodes.

How can I do this code simpler and clearer?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn main() {
    let mut graph = Graph::<i32>::new();
    let n1 = graph.create_node(1);
    let n2 = graph.create_node(2);
    let n3 = graph.create_node(3);
    graph.add_edge(n1.clone(),n2.clone(), 6, false);
    graph.add_edge(n1.clone(),n3.clone(), 7, false);
    graph.get_rel_nodes(n1);
}

type Key = usize;
type Weight = usize;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Node<T: Clone> {
    key: Key,
    value: T
}
impl<T: Clone> Node<T> {
    fn new(value: T, key: Key) -> Self {
        Node{
            key: key,
            value: value
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Graph<T: Clone> {
    map: HashMap<Key, HashMap<Key, Weight>>, // Contains edges
    list: HashMap<Key, Rc<Node<T>>>, // Contains nodes
    next_key: Key,
}

impl<T: Clone> Graph<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Graph {
            map: HashMap::new(),
            list: HashMap::new(),
            next_key: 1,
        }
    }

    // Creates new node with value and return rel for it.
    fn create_node(&mut self, value: T) -> Rc<Node<T>>  {
        let key = self.get_next_key();
        let node = Node::new(value,key);
        let node = Rc::new(node);
        self.list.insert(key, node.clone());
        self.map.insert(key, HashMap::new());
        node
    }

    // Creates new adge between two nodes.
    fn add_edge<N: Borrow<Node<T>>>(&mut self, n1: N, n2: N, weight: Weight, bidirected: bool){
        let key1 = n1.borrow().key;
        let key2 = n2.borrow().key;
        if let Some(map) = self.map.get_mut(&key1) {
            map.insert(key2, weight);
        } else {
            return;
        }
        if bidirected {
            if let Some(map) = self.map.get_mut(&key2) {
                map.insert(key1, weight);
            }
        }
    }

    // Get relative nodes.
    fn get_rel_nodes<N: Borrow<Node<T>>>(&self, node: N) -> Vec<&Rc<Node<T>>> {
        let key = node.borrow().key;
        let rel_keys = self.map.get(&key).unwrap();
        let mut result = vec![];
        for(k,_) in rel_keys {
            result.push(self.list.get(k).unwrap());
        }
        result
    }

    fn get_next_key(&mut self) -> Key {
        let key = self.next_key;
        self.next_key += 1;
        key
    }
}
```